# Complex case with Java Generics. Is it possible in Java?

Tags: java, generics

Instead of this:

```
Fragment<S extends State, ADAPTER extends Adapter<S>>
```

I want to have something like this:

```
Fragment<ADAPTER extends Adapter<S extends State>>
```

Is it possible in Java?

Comment: Did you try using it ? Any errors ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, of course. It produces an error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'S'".

Comment: Are you actually using the `S` type in your implementation code?

Comment: @Bohemian, yes, I use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the type `S`, then your first version is the only way. If you do **not** need to refer to `S` you can use your second version and replace `S` by a `?`:

```
Fragment<ADAPTER extends Adapter<? extends State>>
```

Comment: I need to refer to S. But I want to get rid of redundant type definitions. What for they are needed, if they may be extracted from ADAPTER type?

Comment: If your class refers to `S`, you need to define it as a type parameter. That is just how it works.

Comment: Okey, thank you. I just hoped that there is a syntax that I do not know. Because I think it might be implementable.